# Date Picker for rows that add dynamically with out ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="mytable" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
    <td class="label"><b>Batch Id:</b></FONT></td>  
    <td><input type="text" name="batchId"/></td>
    <td class="label"><b>Start Date:</b></FONT></td>
    <td><input class="datepicker"></td>
    <td><a  id="add">Add New Batch</a></td> 
    </tr>
 </table>

<Script>
$("#add").click(function() {
            $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
            return false;
        });

</Script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ua4bc/65/

Each Row has a start date. Please help me add date picker for each of these startDates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please apply below code for the solution

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();    

$("#add").click(function() {
            $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
    $('#mytable tbody>tr').each(function(i){

        $(this).find(".datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
        $(this).find(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
            return false;
        });
```

Thanks,
Manish Parmar

Comment: I tried this. If I have more than one row. And I try to pick date in second or third row, Value is appended to the first row only. But I want the value to be appended to the same row

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).datepicker().insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7VAZ4/)**

Comment: I still Have the same problem. When I click on "Add New Batch", a new row is added. I should be able to pick date independently for each row. Possible?